# Editar perfil de utilizador url amigável

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess

Boas

Tenho as rotas das urls amigáveis no ficheiro htacess estou a visualizar os users pela url assim pelo ficheiro perfil

http://exmeplo.pt/users/carlos

Mas eu queria agora editar o perfil desse user que e outro ficheiro editar_perfil.php mas queria que a url fica-se assim:

http://exmeplo.pt/users/carlos/edit

Mas nao estou a conseguir por a funcionar

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rotas para o menu principal
RewriteRule ^(comer|dormir|comprar|servicos|lazer|o-que-visitar|login|recuperar-    password|registo|contactos|invite|erro|actualizar-password)$ index.php?controller=$1
# Rotas para os estabelecimentos
RewriteRule ^estabelecimentos/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php? controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=ver_estabelecimento&option=local&local=$1
# Rotas dos Users
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=perfil&option=user_id&user_id=$1
#Erro 404
ErrorDocument 404 /erro
```

Comment: Sempre coloque seu `.htaccess` na pergunta. Sem ele pode ser que alguém proponha uma resposta que não seja compatível com as suas regras atuais.

Comment: Tem razão esquecimento da minha parte já coloquei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
# Rotas dos Users
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=perfil&option=user_id&user_id=$1
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)/edit$ index.php?controller=editar_perfil&option=user_id&user_id=$1
```

RewriteRule funciona sempre neste mesmo formato.

```
RewriteRule [PADRÃO] [SUBSTITUIÇÃO]
```

Ou seja, `PADRÃO` pode conter somente um valor ou pode conter uma [expressão regular](http://www.wikiwand.com/pt/Express%C3%A3o_regular) que será testada sobre o caminho da URL atual. Caso o resultado deste teste seja verdadeiro, o apache vai redirecionar o request para o que estiver definido em `SUBSTITUIÇÃO`.

O trecho `users/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)/edit` é uma expressão regular que irá testar se o caminho da URL segue este padrão e então retornará o que está entre `users/` e `/edit` para a substituição. O `$1` usado na URL de substituição é este valor.

[Veja mais sobre expressões regulares.](http://www.lobo.eti.br/?g_id=10&article=1)

Comment: E isso funcionou direitinho ainda sou novo nisto de urls amigáveis usava sempre por string mas não e o mais indicado vou ter de estudar melhor sobre isso